# python ,1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python-3.x, csv

**TypeError: create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.**

I am getting above error for below codes

without importing CSV, the same code working fine for single object creation
when i try to give input from CSV i am getting below error,

```
from f5.bigip import ManagementRoot
import urllib3
import csv
urllib3.disable_warnings()
mgmt = ManagementRoot('13.126.108.12','admin','admin')
ltm = mgmt.tm.ltm
virtuals = mgmt.tm.ltm.virtuals
virtual = mgmt.tm.ltm.virtuals.virtual

with open('name.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
       reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
       for row in reader:
           virtual1 = mgmt.tm.ltm.virtuals.virtual.create(row['name'], row['description'], row['ip'])
```

i have csv file(name.csv) with three column with  n number rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly believe, that the error message you provided is wrong, because 4 argements were given (self + 3 values from csv).

Anyway the problem is, that `create` expects only key arguments. I believe the last line should look like this:

```
virtual1 = mgmt.tm.ltm.virtuals.virtual.create(
    nam=row['name'],
    description=row['description'],
    ip=row['ip'])
```

Or even

```
virtual1 = mgmt.tm.ltm.virtuals.virtual.create(**row)
```

It depends on which key arguments expects virtual.

Comment: Depending on what's in the CSV file and how `.create(...)` expects its arguments, the OP might even be able to just use `.create(**row)` there...

Comment: Thanks, I am seeing objects are successfully creating in F5 box with input of CSV.    I need one more command, which will give success or failure status in one column( after IP) in CSV file for each ROW.

Comment: @Saravanank It would be another question. This question was about positional and key arguments.

Comment: @Saravanank if the answer was helpful, please consider to upvote it. If it answers your question, you could accept it.